# Forcing participants to be honest in Secure Multiparty Communication

Tags: protocol-design, multiparty-computation

Alice and Bob engage to compute a secure function `f(a,b)` where `a` and `b` must be present in a set `U`. Although both Alice and Bob know `f(a,b)`, how can Alice confirm that `b` is present in `U` and Bob confirm that `a` is present in `U`?

Comment: If Alice revealed all of what is allegedly her information to Bob, then how would Bob confirm that the revealed `a` is present in `U`?

Comment: They should engage in a zero-knowledge proof to prove the membership.

Comment: Why not just use MPC to compute set membership? MPC can compute anything, right. Are you using the garbled circuit variant of MPC or the secret sharing variant?

Comment: Could you clarify the question?   One way for Bob and Alice to prove they know A and B is to send a hash of A or B along (hashed with challenge bytes from the other side)

Answer (score 1):

Try reading this paper https://www.math.ucla.edu/~tdokos/notes_files/garbledCircuits.pdf. It will answer your question.